# How long will a C# lock wait, and what if the code crashes during the lock?

Tags: c#, locking

I saw the following code, and wanted to use it for a simple activity which may only be executed one at a time, and won't occur frequently (so the chance of occurring twice at a time is very small, but you never know).

So the code:

```
// class variable
private static object syncRoot = new object();

// in a method:
lock (syncRoot)
{
    DoIt();
}
```

When another thread comes by and wants to execute the code, how long will it wait until the lock is released? Forever, or can you somehow set a timeout?

And second: if the `DoIt()` method throws an exception, is the lock still released?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

> When another thread comes by and wants to execute the code, how long will it wait until the lock is released?

`lock` will block the the thread trying to enter the lock indefinitely until the object being locked on is released.

> can you somehow set a timeout?

If you need to specify a timeout, use [`Monitor.TryEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter.aspx) as in

```
if(Monitor.TryEnter(obj, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1))) {
    try {
        body 
    }
    finally {
        Monitor.Exit(obj);
    }
}
```

> if the `DoIt()` method throws an exception, is the lock still released?

Yes, a `lock(obj) { body }` is translated to:

```
bool lockWasTaken = false;
var temp = obj;
try { Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockWasTaken); { body } }
finally { if (lockWasTaken) Monitor.Exit(temp); }
```

For the gory details on what can happen when an exception is thrown, see [Locks and exceptions do not mix](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/).

Comment: For a semi-automatic implementation, you can check http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1231461 and http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/03/23/locking (using the using/dispose to automate some of the typing).

Comment: **A fair warning!** The using-statement isn't 100% safe (many tend to think it is!): The using-statement will only call Dispose _if it received the IDisposable-reference_. This happens shortly _after_ the statement inside the using-parentheses, i.e. `using (/*this stuff*/)`, completes. Since there is absolutely no requirement for atomicity (that statement can be arbitrarily long) something can happen there that prevents the (compiler-generated) using-code from ever receiving your clever IDisposable reference. _(tl;dr: keep using-statements simple - put the complicated stuff inside its body.)_

Comment: The link to "Locks and exceptions do not mix" is broken.

Answer (score 43):

As mentioned, a regular lock will wait forever, which is a risk of deadlocks.

The preferred mechanism is (and note the `ref`):

```
bool lockTaken = false;
try {
    Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj, timeout, ref lockTaken);
    if(!lockTaken) throw new TimeoutException(); // or compensate
    // work here...
} finally {
    if(lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
}
```

This avoids the risk of not releasing the lock in some edge-cases.

The `finally` (which exists in any sensible implementation) ensures the lock is released even in error conditions.

Comment: I want to add that a lot of programmers add that finally statement as a _habit_, but a habit it shouldn't be: "Releasing the lock in error conditions" is not auto-magically better than a dead-lock. It is something that should be evaluated on a case-to-case basis. In a safety-critical scenario releasing the lock in a state of error could be dangerous - detecting a dead-locked process and performing some sort of recovery procedure can _sometimes_ be safer than releasing the lock. "Sometimes" being the operative word.

Answer (score 14):

A simple `lock(syncRoot)` will wait forever.

You can replace it with

```
if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(syncRoot, 1000))
{
     try
     {
         DoIt();
     }
     finally
     {
         System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(syncRoot);
     }
}
```

Every thread should ensure exception-safe locking.

Note that the standard `lock(syncRoot) {}` is rewritten to `Monitor.Enter(syncRoot)` and a try/finally

Comment: In c# 4.0 targeting .NET 4 a different overload is called - the `ref lockTaken` version

Answer (score 3):

The lock will wait forever, as Henk said. An exception will still unlock. It is implemented internally with a try-finally block.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a step back and ask yourself why you are letting an exception from a method have any say over when a `Monitor` you `Enter` is `Exit`ed. If there's even a chance that `DoIt()` might throw an exception (and I would argue that if possible you re-write `DoIt()` so that it DoesNot), then you should have a `try/catch` block within the lock() statement so that you can ensure you perform any necessary clean-up.

Comment: I agree this implementation is a simple solution which doesn't require a finally block.

Answer (score 1):

Jason anwser is excellent, here is a way to wrap it making the call simpler.

```
    private void LockWithTimeout(object p_oLock, int p_iTimeout, Action p_aAction)
    {
        Exception eLockException = null;
        bool bLockWasTaken = false;
        try
        {
            Monitor.TryEnter(p_oLock, p_iTimeout, ref bLockWasTaken);
            if (bLockWasTaken)
                p_aAction();
            else
                throw new Exception("Timeout exceeded, unable to lock.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // conserver l'exception
            eLockException = ex;
        }
        finally 
        { 
            // release le lock
            if (bLockWasTaken) 
                Monitor.Exit(p_oLock); 

            // relancer l'exception
            if (eLockException != null)
                throw new Exception("An exception occured during the lock proces.", eLockException);
        }
    }
```

and then, use it this way:

```
        // ajouter à la liste des fiches à loader
        LockWithTimeout(m_lLoadingQueue, 3600, () =>
        {
            m_lLoadingQueue.Add(p_efEcranFiche);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Know the necessary preconditions for deadlock to take place. Always use Monitor vs Lock to avoid deadlocks.

[image: Conditions]